# A Better Side View of Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector

I can't for the life of me remember where this is, but there is a User Agnet CSS file out there for Google Chrome Dev Tools that someone created to have a better layout when using side view. Anyone know this link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it here:

Mac: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css

PC: C:UsersYourUsernameAppDataLocalGoogleChromeUser DataDefaultUser StyleSheetsCustom.css ~Thanks to @VSC

Ubuntu (Chromium): ~/.config/chromium/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css ~Thanks to @Carlos

As per http://darcyclarke.me/design/skin-your-chrome-inspector/

Comment: I eventually found the css file but this is a much better way to remember. thanks for the link!